# Tensor product of two $R$-modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

$R$ a ring. Given $M$ a right $R$-module and N a left $R$-module, we define the tensor product

$$M \otimes_R N$$
where (among other properties) $mr \otimes n = m\otimes rn$ holds for all $r \in R, m \in M, n \in N$.

My question is probably trivial but why do we care so much about $M$ being a right module and $N$ being a left one? Couldn't we just define something where $rm \otimes n = m\otimes rn$ holds, in the case they are both left $R$-modules? Can someone give me an example of why this is actually important?

Comment: For the usual tensor product there is an existence and uniqueness theorem. Well, maybe the object you are describing does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that this is because the tensor product is made to study bilinear forms, and that bilinear forms are usually asked to satisfy $b(mr,n)=b(m,rn)$.

More precisely, recall that a bilinear form $b:M\times N\to X$, where $X$ is any abelian group, is a map satisfying

1. $b(m_1+m_2, n_1+n_2) = b(m_1,n_1)+b(m_1,n_2)+b(m_2,n_1)+b(m_2,n_2)$, and
2. $b(mr,n)=b(m,rn)$,

for all $m,m_1,m_2\in M$, $n,n_1,n_2\in N$ and $r\in R$.

The tensor product of $M$ and $N$ is then defined to be a kind of repository of "universal expressions involving bilinear forms".  This is made precise in its universal property: if $t:M\times N \to M\otimes N$ is the defining map, then for any bilinear map $b:M\times N\to X$, there is a unique morphism of abelian groups $\overline{b}:M\otimes N \to X$ such that $\overline{b}t=b$.

---

Now, you could very well decide that you are not interested in bilinear maps, but instead in maps $c:M\times N\to X$ (with $M$ and $N$ now both *left* modules) satisfying

3. $c(m_1+m_2, n_1+n_2) = c(m_1,n_1)+c(m_1,n_2)+c(m_2,n_1)+c(m_2,n_2)$, and
4. $c(rm,n)=c(m,rn)$,

for all $m,m_1,m_2\in M$, $n,n_1,n_2\in N$ and $r\in R$.  Note that property 4 is not the same as 2.

You could then define a new object, say $M\otimes' N$, with the universal property that it comes with a map $s:M\times N\to M\otimes' N$ satisfying properties 3 and 4, and such that whenever you have a map $c:M\times N\to X$ satisfying 3 and 4, there is a unique morphism of abelian groups $\overline{c}:M\otimes' N \to X$ such that $\overline{c}s=c$.

You could then construct such an object as you would the tensor product; in short, its elements would be linear combinations of symbols of the form $m\otimes' n$, subject to linearity in $m$ and $n$, and to $rm\otimes' n = m\otimes' rn$.

---

So I guess a short answer to your question would be: the property you want *could* be imposed, but it is not the one we choose to study, because bilinear forms.

Comment: Thank you, this makes a lot of sense. Only one small comment: what about the issue Math137 points out in his answer?

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 I would not call it an issue, but a property of $M\otimes' N$.  It does mean that many more elements of the form $m\otimes' n$ will become equal to each other than in the usual tensor product.

Comment: Ok so it would be a totally different thing. Thank you for the insight

Comment: Suppose as @Pierre-GuyPlamondon described in their answer the object $M\otimes^\prime N$ exists and has the universal property, then we would have $_R(R\otimes^\prime_R R) \simeq {_RR}$, this means $ab=ab.1=ba.1=ba$ for all $a,b\in R$? That is what I concluded? please correct me

Comment: @Math137 I don't think we would have $R\otimes' R$ isomorphic to $R$, but rather to $R/[R,R]$, where $[R,R]$ is the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $ab-ba$, with $a,b\in R$.  And yes, in this object $R\otimes' R$, we would have $a\otimes' b = b\otimes' a$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon I would like to understand this situation more, how about the maps $\phi: {_R(R\otimes^\prime_R R)}\to {_RR}$ given by $a\otimes^\prime b\mapsto ab$ and $\psi: {_RR}\to {_R(R\otimes^\prime_R R)}$ given by $a\mapsto a\otimes^\prime 1$?They are inverse of each other? arent they?Or the first one has kernel? I am a bit confused. This is what I think $\phi\psi(a)=\phi(a\otimes^\prime 1)=a$ and $\psi\phi(a\otimes^\prime b)=\psi(ab)=ab\otimes^\prime 1=ab.1\otimes^\prime 1=ba.1\otimes^\prime 1=a\otimes^\prime b$

Comment: @Math137 The map $\phi$ that you write is not well defined.  In $R\otimes' R$, we have $a\otimes' b = b\otimes' a$.  If $\phi$ were well-defined, this would mean that $ab=ba$ in $R$...  However, the map $\psi$ that you write is well-defined, and its kernel should be $[R,R]$.

Comment: @Pierre-GuyPlamondon thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition $rm \otimes n = m\otimes rn$ would  work when $R$ is commutative, since in which case left $R$ modules are right $R^{op}=R$ modules.

But in case of noncommutative rings $rm \otimes n = m\otimes rn$  does not work, since this would lead to $m \otimes (rs).n = m\otimes (sr).n$ in the following way  $$m \otimes (rs).n=m \otimes r.(s.n)=r.m \otimes s.n=s.(r.m) \otimes n=(sr).m \otimes n=m\otimes (sr).n$$